# How do I get the ID of multiple inserted rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert, normalization

I am inserting some words into a two-column table with this command:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO terms (term) VALUES ('word1'), ('word2'), ('word3');
```

1. How can I get the ID (Primary Key) of the row in which each word is inserted. I mean returning a value like "55,56,57" after executing `INSERT`. Does MySQL have such a response?
2. The term column is `UNIQUE`. If a term already exists, MySQL will not insert it. Is it possible to return the reference for this duplication (i.e. the ID of the row in which the term exists)? A response like "55,**12**,56".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1. You get it via [`SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html) or via having your framework/MySQL library (in whatever language) call [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-insert-id.html).
2. That won't work. There you have to query the IDs after inserting.

Comment: Right - not in one with `INSERT IGNORE`. But in a non-`IGNORE` one, it gives you the first value generated and inserted.

Comment: What if another user has made another insert in the meanwhile?

Comment: @Pitto Nevertheless you would get the correct value from `LAST_INSERT_ID()` resp. `mysql_insert_id()`. The former knows what has last happened in the current session, the latter is directly bound to the last query. If something else happens in a different connection, that doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
SELECT ID
  FROM terms
 WHERE term IN ('word1', 'word2', 'word3')
```

Comment: That'd fetch terms that were previously inserted, and it'd be vulnerable to a race condition where something else inserts records before the select query fires.

Comment: ??  term has a UNIQUE condition.  The only thing that could affect the SELECT in a race condition is a DELETE, not another INSERT.  And according to (2) in OP's post, they want the previously inserted records' IDs to be included.

Comment: That's what I had in mind; but it needs few lines of coding. Apart from SELECT, I need fetch the results and get them in a while loop (in php that I use). I hope to find some kind of mysql response.

Comment: @Googlebot this is the best way to go about it. If you want to iterate over the IDs, just execute a `SELECT` (shown in this answer) and iterate over the results. _What's in a few more lines of coding anyway?_ If you really want MySQL to echo the ID, you have to issue separate single `INSERT` statements and execute `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` after each `INSERT` to collect the IDs into an array.

Answer (score 0):

First, to get the id just inserted, you can make something like :

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() ;
```

Care, this will work only after your last `INSERT` query and it will return the **first ID only** if you have a multiple insert!

Then, with the `IGNORE` option, I don't think that it is possible to get the lines that were not inserted. When you make an `INSERT IGNORE`, you just tell MySQL to ignore the lines that would have to create a duplicate entry.

If you don't put this option, the `INSERT` will be stopped and you will have the line concerned by the duplication.

Comment: Even without IGNORE, it will only works for single-row INSERT. My command is a multi-row INSERT

Comment: Only the first part of my answer was including the IGNORE.

Comment: If you're using PHP, you can store the IDs in a table using a loop with a single INSERT in each passage.