# Getting a Variable From a Database via an SQL Command

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, variables

Here is my code:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO third (id2, language, divid, point, ce, datetime, IP)  VALUES ('$id2', '$language', '$new_divid', 0, 'b', NOW(), '$ipaddress')");
```

In this code ([MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)) I add a new line to the database and I didn't add a `id1` column to it, cause `id1` is auto-increment in the table - it adds `id1` automatically.

Now what I am trying is tp get `id1` back, inside the ***same*** SQL command BUT I don't want use PHP again and again. Is this possible?

**Note:** I saw something like `OUTPUT INSERTED.id1` but I didn't understand what it is and whether i can use it. ([I saw it in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999396/how-do-i-use-an-insert-statements-output-clause-to-get-the-identity-value))

Comment: Have you checked the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` mysql function? Have you done a Google search on your problem topic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the ID of INSERTed row in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501464/how-to-get-the-id-of-inserted-row-in-mysql)