# My Sql Return ID value after insert data in MySql?

Tags: mysql, database, asp-classic

I am using MySql with classic asp. And i am inserting data in MySql Database.

I am Using this code to return ID when data is inserted. 
But it returns 0.
so, is there any solution for return ID from MySql Database ?

```
Insert into table(name,lastname,username) Output Inserted.ID values("abc","def","ghi")
```

this returns value 0. So, how can i get ?

Comment: which programming language are you using? where is the front end code?

Comment: I am using classic asp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the ID of INSERTed row in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501464/how-to-get-the-id-of-inserted-row-in-mysql)

Comment: so, you will down the vote. why ?

Comment: I flagged the question as a duplicate ( and it is the answer proves it), maybe that's why it's been down-voted?

Comment: but, i can't find that question. so, i asked on this site. If you have any problem then don't answer.

Comment: But, don't down the vote of anyone.

Comment: @Nikunj You obviously don't understand how this site works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function.