# Insert and get new id in one query recordset

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, recordset

I need to insert a row in asp-classic and mysql and get his unique id.
Here is my code:

```
sql = "insert into o_operaciones (idoperacion, fechaalta, nombre)"
sql = sql & ") VALUES ("
sql = sql & "DEFAULT,now(),'" & nombre & "');"
sql = sql & "SELECT max(idoperacion) as id from o_operaciones; "
Set rsInsert = Conex.Execute(sql)
idoperacion = cdbl(rsInsert("id"))
```

With this code i don´t have errors but the recordset it´s empty or closed after execute.

I know there is another ways to do the same, but i think this is the faster.

I tried `SET NOCOUNT` but don't work in MySql.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the ID of INSERTed row in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501464/how-to-get-the-id-of-inserted-row-in-mysql)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you can do that the way you are trying to.

You can use something like the following if you're able / don't mind using stored procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
    @col1            VARCHAR(20),
    @new_id    INT    OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO MyTable (col1)
    VALUES (@col1)

    SELECT @new_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    SELECT @new_id AS id

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Last time I looked that isn't MySQL syntax.

Comment: Oops I didn't even notice it was MySQL, I don't think of that in the same breath as  asp.

Comment: Maybe you could put in the the MySQL version if a similar thing is doable?

Comment: It pays to read the question before wading in with an answer. The OP clearly stated *"asp-classic and mysql"*.

Comment: I would but it's not something the OP couldn't find with a quick Google search, it's not an uncommon request infact I'm sure it would have been answered on [so] before.